# Where does Windows store permissions for the Registry

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, permissions, windows-registry

Every Windows Registry key has a permissions list to specify which user(s) can read or modify the key.

Where is this list stored?

Is it the same location for Windows 7 and 10?

Is there any way, when logged in as admin, to tell if the permissions for any key have been changed by a user or admin (without going through every key and checking manually)?

Comment: It's stored with the key like it is stored with the file entry for files. You can turn on auditing but not on home. But why would you want to do this?